# Are electrical properties measured using the International system of units (SI)?

Tags: electricity, system

What measurement system is used to measure electrical properties such as voltage, current, etc.?
I understand the units are defined by SI (at least according to [this](https://www.britannica.com/science/ampere) article), but is that considered the measurement system used to measure properties of electricity?

It is confusing me because I have some people telling me that scientific notation is required for it to be considered part of the SI system, and that engineering notation is not part of the SI system.

So I am unclear if I am indeed using the SI system when measuring electrical properties. If not, then what system am I using?

To clear up ambiguity, the old definition of "the metric system" is not intended to be the topic of the question. I aim to clarify that any statements I make that refer to "the metric system" in comments refer to the modern  International System of Units (SI).

Comment: SI is based on and extending the metric system. I really do not understand your other questions.

Comment: OK, I will update my question. As far as I can tell the metric system is synonymous with the International System of Units.

Comment: Your link has another link defining precisely what SI system is. [Here it is](https://www.britannica.com/science/International-System-of-Units) if you missed.

Comment: Oh ok. So the answer would be yes then? Does the International System of Units  body define how engineering notation is noted/written?

Comment: As far as I know, SI system has nothing to say about scientific/engineering notation. Engineering notation is even set so that it matches SI prefixes, so I don't see how it would be wrong to use it.

Comment: *[...] that scientific notation is required for it to be considered part of the SI system, and that engineering notation is not part of the metric system.* Weird claim. When i read [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation), i think engineering notation matches the SI prefix better than scientific notation, because engineering notation and the SI prefix both are (mainly) based on powers of 1000.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "engineering notation?" Also, have a look at [NIST Special Publication 330](https://www.nist.gov/sites/default/files/documents/2016/12/07/sp330.pdf) (which I think is what defines the SI).

Comment: [Engineering Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation) is where the exponents are divisible by 3 I believe. I.E. 1.5KA vs. 1.5 * 10^3A

Comment: So you are talking about the SI prefixes like k, m, n, etc.? Or are you talking about using scientific notation with initial values not between 1 and 2, like 15.1 × 10³ A instead of 1.51 × 10⁴ A?

Comment: Anyway, as far as I can tell, SI does not have anything to say about the formatting of the number portion of a value. Unless you are using SI prefixes by themselves without units, that's explicitly not allowed (e.g., saying a fraction equals "1 n" to mean 1e-9). Can you give a specific example that they said was incorrect?

Comment: Ampere is the only electrical related SI base unit.

Comment: @KingDuken  What about Farad? Or Ohm?

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry, I meant SI base* unit.

Comment: @KingDuken Still, I think Volt is SI anyway. Perhaps not SI-derived, but still SI. Watt which is Volt times Ampere is SI. And it is not in the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-SI_units_mentioned_in_the_SI). *Update:* Actually it *is* SI-derived: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit

Comment: @justin my question is more "what system am I using?" and not, "how do I write down 3 amps." For Example: If a person were to ask me how to measure distance, and I were to tell them "in meters" and then they were to ask "is that the metric system?" I would say "Yes!" Similarly, if one were to say that a person measures current in Amperes, and I asked "is that the metric system?" It is similar to that line of reasoning. Whether or not one likes the metric system is irrelevant. I would go so far as to say how one writes it down is irrelevant also, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "metric system" is not the correct terminology. We use the **SI**, the International System of Units that defines certain **base** units as well as a much larger set of **derived** units. The base units must be defined in terms of reproducible physical phenomena, then the derived units are defined in terms of the base units.

The ampere is a base unit. According to IEEE/ASTM standard SI 10-2016:

> The ampere is that constant current that, if maintained in two
>   straight parallel conductors of infinite length, of negligible
>   circular cross section, and placed one meter apart in a vacuum, would
>   produce between these conductors a force equal to \$2\times 10^{-7}\$
>   newton per meter of length.

The volt, the farad, the coulomb, etc. are derived units.

The SI does not say that you can or can not use exponential notation and it does not specify what "engineering notation" would be. It tells you what letter to use for the symbol for a unit (e.g. F for farad) and specifies the prefixes that can be used instead of exponential notation. There are quite a few other rules and suggestions...too many to include here.

Comment: Except that "electricity" is not measured with the SI or anything else. There are SI units for current, voltage, charge, capacitance, inductance, power, and energy but there is no unit for "electricity".

Comment: I updated my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: The SI system is used to specify quantities of electrical properties. However, the use of exponential notation, scientific notation, and/or engineering format is unrelated to the use of the SI.

Comment: I am gratefully attempting understand what you are trying to suggest. Are you saying the measurement system used to identify properties of electricity is SI, or am I not understanding?

Comment: Yes, the measurement system used to quantify characteristics or properties of phenomena related to "electricity" is SI.

Comment: OK, I didn't clearly understand, but your comment clarified that the "measurement system used to quantify characteristics or properties of phenomena related to 'electricity' is SI."